# Subsetting a data frame and replacing a column based on condition

Tags: r

I am working on a data frame with three columns labelled as id, time1 and time2. A sample is:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
      time1 = c(12L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 30L, 3L, 30L, 7L, 2L, 17L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 22L, 5L, 15L, 4L, 7L, 23L),
      time2=c(23L,23L,23L,23L,23L,22L,22L,22L,22L,22L,25L,25L,25L,25L,25L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L)
    ),
    .Names = c("id", "time1","time2"),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-20L)
  )
```

I am using R and I am trying to subset this data and replace column `time2` with a new column based on the following criteria:

1. Sum the values of `time1` for each `id` until it is greater than or equal to the corresponding value of `time2` for that `id`.
2. Replace the cells in `time1` where the summations terminate with the corresponding `time2` value for each `id`.
3. Column `time2` is to be replaced with a new column labelled as `status` which consists of `0`'s and `1`'s. That is, `status` takes on `1` for the non-replaced values of `time1` and `0` for all the replaced values of `time1`.

In summary, I am expecting to see something like this:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
      time1 = c(12L, 5L, 3L, 23, 22L, 17L, 5L, 25L, 5L, 15L, 24L),
      status=c(1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L)
    ),
    .Names = c("id", "time1","status"),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-11L)
  )
```

I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        status = as.numeric(cumsum(time1) < time2),
        time1 = ifelse(status == 1, time1, time2)) %>%
    group_by(id, status) %>%
    mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(status == 1 | (status == 0 & n == 1)) %>%
    select(-n, -time2)
## A tibble: 11 x 3
#      id time1 status
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1    12     1.
# 2     1     5     1.
# 3     1     3     1.
# 4     1    23     0.
# 5     2    22     0.
# 6     3    17     1.
# 7     3     5     1.
# 8     3    25     0.
# 9     4     5     1.
#10     4    15     1.
#11     4    24     0.
```

Explanation: We group rows by `id`, then calculate the cumulative sum of `time1` entries, and flag those rows where `cumsum(time1) < time2` with `1`, else with `0`; we replace `time1` entries with `time2` entries if `status == 1`. Lastly we need to remove excess `status = 0` rows; to do so, we regroup by `id` and `status`, number rows consecutively, and keep only one row for `status = 0` per `id`.